# How do I connect different namespaces and modules in Python

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I'm developing a physical model using Python. I right now have four files (I suppose I can call them modules but I really am no Python expert) in one folder. Right now it works just fine but after reading a bit it turned out the way I do it could lead to errors when further expanding my model (by using from ... import* statement).

(1) **initialize**: Does nothing except for calling the **plot**() module with some information about what to plot. Here I would like to set some initial parameters which won't change during the computation and pass them to the **compute** module. *Imports* **plot**

(2) **compute**: Contains initial values (which I actually want to set in **initialize** module) and all the computation algorithm. During computation, functions which are stored in **functions** module are being called a lot. *Imports*  **functions**

(3) **functions**: Contains actual physical functions.

(4) **plot**: Contains all the plots. *Imports* everything from **compute** (from compute import *)

Originally I only had the **compute** and the **functions** module. When I started plotting however, the **compute** module became too big (in my eyes) so I wanted to split. I realized I would need to pass all the variables I calculated in **compute** (quite a few) as arguments to the **plot** module. Or alternatively import the **compute** module with a prefix (e.g. import compute as com --> com.variable). I didn't like both options too much. So i decided to use the from **compute** import * statement, which allows me to use the same variable names as originally defined in **compute**. This looks a lot cleaner to me and makes it easier to read to variable names.

The problem is, when importing **compute** into my **plot** module (to get all the variable names) the code in **compute** is executed. But I would like to call **compute** from my **initialize** module to set up the initial parameters. However If i do so i would need to call **compute** twice, which takes a lot more time. Besides that, from ... import * apparently is not a good choice.
I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

### On the import statements

The main reason to avoid `from my_model import *` statements is, that it obscures which variables are imported (and available in the scope after the importing) and where does the variables comes from. For example if you have:

```
from mod1 import *
from mod2 import *
...
print(my_var)
```

... it is not immediately clear if the `my_var` comes from `mod1` or `mod2`. Furthermore, lets say, we define `my_var` in `mod1` and then during the development we define `my_var` also in `mod2` (for example even without exporting it at all), suddenly `my_var` is something else which may lead to weird errors. And if you are using chained imports, it is really hard to keep track which import gets executed first and which last, so generally you need to make sure you never define variables with clashing names.

This problem is somewhat (personally, I still think it is worth avoiding just for that reason) mitigated with usage of modern IDEs which can point out clashing names, however it is still subject to overlooking. However, speaking of the IDEs... if you know a function you need is in a specific module -- if you imported the module as `import my_mod` -- you can type `my_mod.` and the IDE shows you the options, if you import it via `from my_mod import *` its not so easy.

For these reason it is generally recommended to use plain `import my_mod` or using aliases `import my_mod as mm` which have none of these problems. I know you mentioned you don't like this approach but maybe it is worth reconsidering. Nevertheless, if you still don't like it there is a middle ground of `from my_mod import var_1, var_2, func`. Then you don't have to write `mm.` every time you need the variables. It has a drawback that every time you want to use a new variable defined in `my_mod` you'll need to add it to the `import` statement as well, however on the bright side, this approach would make you sure you don't import clashing variables (as while adding it to `import` statement you can cross-check with other `import`s, and also it will make sure that you don't end up importing some variables that you don't want to import.

Nonetheless, if you are building your own small project you might indeed end up using `from my_mod import *` just be aware of the drawbacks mentioned above.

### On the execution while `import`ing

The fact that some (non-trivial) code gets executed during `import` statement suggests bad code design. During the `import` call, the only code that gets "executed" is the code written in the "top scope". That is, if there are some functions etc. these function (naturally) don't get executed, just... defined. However if you have some "direct" code in the "top scope", for example:

```
print(42)
```

this code will get executed (and prints `42`) when first encountered appropriate `import` statement.

In most cases in this "top scope" should be just only class/function definitions and occasionally some global variables. All other code should be enclosed in some function or class or method... exactly for the reason, so it wouldn't be executed at the `import` statement. So if you have some code, which you wish to execute at specific moment, wrap that part of the code in a function a call that function (from the other module), rather than relying on the `import` statement to execute the code.

Note that there are some exceptions to aforementioned "rule". Most notably, if you want some code to gets executed when you call the file via `python3 my_file.py` you **need** to put the code you wish to be executed in the "top level". However even in this case this code should be put within `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard for this reason -- not to execute the code on `import` (just when "calling the file" directly), additionally, it is a good practice to have a very short code within this guard (for example just calling some function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I could use aliases in my "plot" module to avoid the name Clash problem. But, as u said, code execution on import statements should be avoided. However, if I use some function in my "compute" module which starts the computation (to avoid code execution), all the calculated variables are defined in that local namespace of that starting function right? Then i cannot just import these variables I want to plot to my "plot" module anymore, because they are not in the global namespace.

Comment: @AimLow To assign to global namespace use `global` keyword (using `global a` `a = 42` would set `a` in global namespace). However, this would me you would be using global namespace again... that is usually something you want to avoid, but if it's just your small project it might be fine. Better solution could be defining classes and that way you would need to just pass one object containing all the data. But it is hard to say without actually seeing to code... and I might not be the best person for that anyway

Answer (score 0):

for namespace you can check python document
and for module put command in terminal

pip install (module name)

example:-

pip install flask
#the flask module is automatically download in your system

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).